# Onkeypress function not working on bootstrap input box

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I've been trying to code a function that goes to a different page when the user hits the enter key into a certain input box. Here's the code:

```
<div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <form>
            <div id="search" onkeypress="enter(event)" >
                <div class="input-group col-md-offset-8 col-md-3">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control">
                    <div class="input-group-btn">
                        <a href="mylink.com" tab-index="-1" class="btn btn-default" type="submit"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i></a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            </form>
        </div>
</div>

    <script>
            function enter(event){
                if (event.keyCode == 13){
                    document.location.href = "newpage.com";
                }
            }
    </script>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Though I would encourage you not to use event attributes, It works for me. What browser are you using?

Comment: place your keypress function on input box.

Comment: I'm using Google Chrome

Comment: @J.C I tried that but it doesn't change anything...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's happening is simple, you have a "form" tag, so when you hit enter, "onkeypress" is firing the event and the function "enter" that you created is handling that event, but having a "form" tag it just submitting a form.

To avoid that, just remove the "form" tag or just replace it for the following:

```
<form onsubmit="event.preventDefault();">
```

Also, you have to add the protocol if you want to redirect to a different page, like:

```
document.location.href = "http://newpage.com";
```

I hope it helps :)

Comment: I added the onsubmit attribute to the form tag and it worked! Thank you!